# Change Desktop display manager

Tags: 16.04, display-manager

How do I change the Dell factory pre-installed display manager in 16.04LTS.  I have the one I want already downloaded but settings doesn't give me a choice.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`  or gdm, or whatever you installed or have installed.  You'll be asked a question asking which to use (of the ones installed)

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and enter

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

You'll be prompted with a list of the DMs you have installed, and asked which you want to configure.  You could equally use your newly-installed DM in place of lightdm (eg. `gdm3` which is the new default for Ubuntu 18.04) as it lists your choices.